# NuxtJS & Vuetify - Webpack build exited with errors

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I use **Vuetify v0.17.6** and **NuxtJS v1.3.0**.

I get this error when I push my project on production: https://pastebin.com/AJWHZE9q

I think is the import of Vuetify as plugin on NuxtJS.

My **vuetify.js** file for NuxtJS plugin:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'

import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'

Vue.use(Vuetify, {
  theme: {
    primary: "#F57C00",
    secondary: "#EF6C00",
    accent: "#E65100",
    error: "#F44336",
    warning: "#ffeb3b",
    info: "#2196F3",
    success: "#4CAF50"
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the root cause!

I downgraded **postcss-loader v2.1.2** package in my project with this command:

> npm install postcss-loader@^2.1.1 --save-dev

or

> yarn add postcss-loader@^2.1.1 -D

An option was changed in *node_modules/postcss-loader/lib/options.json*

And I forgot to commit the **yarn.lock** file.